# zsh - first tab completion with autocd

Tags: zsh, tab-completion, zsh-completion, completion

I am currently switching from csh to zsh I am writing a .zshrc trying to get all the options I am used to in this new shell.

I use autocd (to go into a directory just typing its name (without the cd command), and I wonder if it is possible that my first  propose all the files existing in the current directory (like it's working in csh).

I am quite used to this way of having an overview of the files I can open or directory I can "autocd" into, before typing my command just pressing  without anything written in my commandline yet.

Right now when I first press  it does not trigger any completion mechanism but it just write an actual tabulation.

I did not find any solution yet, and if anyone has any magic options to get this results, feel free to enlighten me!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found a way!
No need for autocd, though this option exists in zsh
To put in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
first-tab() {
    if [[ $#BUFFER == 0 ]]; then
        BUFFER="cd "
        CURSOR=3
        zle list-choices
    else
        zle expand-or-complete
    fi
}
zle -N first-tab
bindkey '^I' first-tab
```

Thanks to this question: [zsh tab completion on empty line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14230/zsh-tab-completion-on-empty-line)

So press tab once and you will get "cd " and the existing directories.

Checkout `man zshoptions` for other existing options which could be useful
(`setopt menucomplete` could be useful to save a tab, but change behaviour for other completion as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another more complex variation.

- It will list **files** on  on an empty command line, and in the middle of any command.
- It will list **directories** on  on an empty command line.
- It will list **executables** on  on an empty command line.

It can be configured to prepend "cd " or "./" in those cases with a global variable.

`export TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX`

[image: tab_list_files_example]

```
# List files in zsh with <TAB>
#
# Copyleft 2017 by Ignacio Nunez Hernanz <nacho _a_t_ ownyourbits _d_o_t_ com>
# GPL licensed (see end of file) * Use at your own risk!
#
# Usage:
#   In the middle of the command line:
#     (command being typed)<TAB>(resume typing)
#
#   At the beginning of the command line:
#     <SPACE><TAB>
#     <SPACE><SPACE><TAB>
#
# Notes:
#   This does not affect other completions
#   If you want 'cd ' or './' to be prepended, write in your .zshrc 'export TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX'
#   I recommend to complement this with push-line-or edit (bindkey '^q' push-line-or-edit)
function tab_list_files
{
  if [[ $#BUFFER == 0 ]]; then
    BUFFER="ls "
    CURSOR=3
    zle list-choices
    zle backward-kill-word
  elif [[ $BUFFER =~ ^[[:space:]][[:space:]].*$ ]]; then
    BUFFER="./"
    CURSOR=2
    zle list-choices
    [ -z ${TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX+x} ] && BUFFER="  " CURSOR=2
  elif [[ $BUFFER =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
    BUFFER="cd "
    CURSOR=3
    zle list-choices
    [ -z ${TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX+x} ] && BUFFER=" " CURSOR=1
  else
    BUFFER_=$BUFFER
    CURSOR_=$CURSOR
    zle expand-or-complete || zle expand-or-complete || {
      BUFFER="ls "
      CURSOR=3
      zle list-choices
      BUFFER=$BUFFER_
      CURSOR=$CURSOR_
    }
  fi
}
zle -N tab_list_files
bindkey '^I' tab_list_files

# uncomment the following line to prefix 'cd ' and './' 
# when listing dirs and executables respectively
#export TAB_LIST_FILES_PREFIX

# these two lines are usually included by oh-my-zsh, but just in case
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

# uncomment the following line to complement tab_list_files with ^q
#bindkey '^q' push-line-or-edit

# License
#
# This script is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this script; if not, write to the
# Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330,
# Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
```

More details in [this post](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/30/list-files-without-stopping-to-type-in-zsh/)